# Sqllite search column name in db

Tags: sqlite, search

I have a db in sqllite and it has almost 140 tables and many columns. And I don't know which table contain what column I have a specific requirement to search for specific column name
.

For example I have a database called msg. And it has almost 100 tables after lots of try I am unable to find exact column name like I am searching for localid in db from all table. I am using Sqllitestudio to see the db.

My question is can I search for just a column name and in which table or in how many tables that particular column exist.

Comment: How to search a column name in DB browser for SQLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start the sqlite commandline tool.
Ask the "table of tables" about anything mentioning " localid " in the creation statement.

```
create table toy1 (thisid int, aletter char(1), anotherint int);
create table toy2 (globalid int, aletter char(1), localid int);
select * from sqlite_master where sql like '% localid %';
```

Output (with `.headers on`, in SQLite 3.18.0):

```
type        name        tbl_name    rootpage    sql
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  --------------------------------------------------------------
table       toy2        toy2        3           CREATE TABLE toy2 (globalid int, aletter char(1), localid int)
```

Edit the "where" clause to make the filter tighter or more generous, depending on what you need.